# I cant add a data into the sql via EF (Non static method requires a target)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my MVC project, Im tryna add a bike to my db, but i cannot.
Here's my code:

```
public override ServiceResult New(Bike entity)
    {
        var bike = repository.Select(x => x.Brand == entity.Brand && x.Model == entity.Model);
            if (bike.Any())
            {
                return new ServiceResult(ServiceResultCode.Generic, "This bike is already exists.");
            }
                return base.New(entity);            
    }
```

And let me show you other connected classes and maybe you'll get that where the wrong part is.

Here is my GenericRepository class.

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
    {
        if (Filter != null)
        {
            return _dbSet.Where(Filter);
        }
        return _dbSet;
    }
```

when i press the add button. It's like "Dude stop, you dont know what you're trying!" Like a guardian. Maybe a little help?

Comment: What line throws the exception? Are the values as expected up to that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, if this is your first foray into Entity Framework, start simple before trying to delve into things like repository patterns. IMHO while a repository pattern is very useful for isolating your domain from your logic to test that logic, the Generic repository pattern is an anti-pattern.  Immediately the first problem is returning `IEnumerable<T>`, to maintain the benefit of EF with Linq expressions, repositories should return `IQueryable<T>`.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
{
   if (Filter != null)
       return _dbSet.Where(Filter);
   return _dbSet;
}
```

vs.

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null)
{
   if (Filter != null)
       return _dbSet.Where(Filter);
   return _dbSet;
}
```

Both methods appear to work, but they do two completely different things. Both methods will triggered a deferred execution for the query when you execute the `.Any()` statement, however when you return `IEnumerable<T>`, the query will execute as effectively a `SELECT * FROM [T]` where if you return `IQueryable<T>` the query will execute as a `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS` essentially running a query to just return whether a row exists or not. Any operation you use, the first example will always be doing a `SELECT *` where the second has the opportunity to generate more efficient and precise queries.

To start narrowing down the root of your problem though, start simple with just the DbContext and the entities. Generally it's not a good idea to pass entities around between client and server as it exposes your schema and generally passes more information than the client needs to display. It also leads to lazy load hits when serializing or potentially errors/#null data with cyclic references or if lazy loading is disabled to get around these problems. Data coming from a client should also never be trusted, so any code that might attach a passed in entity set state to Modified and save to the database risks harmful data injection attacks.

But looking at your original example, start by reducing it down to the simplest possible thing without getting dug right in to repositories and inheritance:

```
public override ServiceResult New(Bike entity)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var bikeExists = context.Bikes.Any(x => x.Brand = entity.Brand 
            && x.Model == entity.Model);
        if (bikeExists)
            return new ServiceResult(ServiceResultCode.Generic, "This bike is already exists.");

        var newBike = new Bike
        {
            Brand = entity.Brand,
            Model = entity.Model,
            // Copy over only data you trust after validating it.
        };
        context.Bikes.Add(newBike);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return new ServiceResult(ServiceResultCode.Success, "Bike added.");
    }
}
```

If that works, then re-factor to reintroduce common base class functionality, repositories, etc. This will help identify where/what elements are tripping you up. Writing code to best practices is something I recommend that developers re-factor code towards rather than try to write from scratch especially when starting out with unfamiliar technologies. Often the attempts to write efficient code make problems harder to identify and fix. The end goal would be to reintroduce a repository, a unit of work, and a view model for communication between client and server. It would end up looking something like:

```
public override ServiceResult New(NewBikeViewModel newBike)
{
    using (var contextScope = ContextScopeFactory.Create())
    {
        var bikeExists = BikeRepository.Bikes.Any(x => x.Brand = newBike.Brand 
            && x.Model == newBike.Model);
        if (bikeExists)
            return new ServiceResult(ServiceResultCode.Generic, "This bike is already exists.");

        var bike = BikeRepository.Create(newBike.Brand, newBike.Model);
        // Can fill in any optional details from the view model into bike here.
        contextScope.SaveChanges();
        return new ServiceResult(ServiceResultCode.Success, "Bike added.");
    }
}
```

NewBikeViewModel represents a model from the view containing the data to identify a new bike. I utilize a Unit of Work pattern called Mehdime DbContextScope which coordinates a context scope between business logic (controllers) and repositories. The repository locates it's scope (throwing an exception if you call it outside of one) and uses that to get the DbContext. Context Scopes or Units of Work are nice because they form a boundary for committing changes. The issue with something like a DbContext being injected and limited to a lifetime scope such as the request is that it is all or nothing for everything. Any change that attempts to commit in the context and fails remains associated to that context and will prevent that context from saving anything else. The BikeRepository is not a Generic repository, it is a repository that services bikes. This includes retrieving data, but also creating data. It serves as a factory for Bikes to ensure that all required information is passed in. It is also in the position to ensure that any references to other entities can be set up to ensure that a new Bike is always returned in a complete enough state. Create takes parameters for all *required* fields/references. Any optional data can be filled in afterwards before the changes are saved.   This is only an example of the patterns I use, the key thing is to start with the simplest thing then move towards the target structure you want to adopt.